# Render docstring with Sphinx in Jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-sphinx

Is there a way to make Jupyter notebooks render docstrings that contain Sphinx markup correctly in a Jupyter notebooks.

At the moment if I have a `Foo` class with Sphinx documentation and the user tries to get the docstring with

```
[1] Foo.bar?
```

They end up with the raw text. E.g.

```
Calls the :py:meth:`bar` method of the :py:class:`Foo` class.
```

Is there a way to make Jupyter automatically render the docstring correctly as Sphinx. Or anything that's easier to read than raw rst?

Comment: SageMath does this, I believe using its "sphinxify" code: https://github.com/sagemath/sage/blob/develop/src/sage/misc/sphinxify.py. That is not easy to use out of the box — it has various SageMath specific things in it — but maybe you can adapt it.

Comment: Not as easy as I'd hoped, but I can make that work!

Comment: I'll add this as an actual answer, then. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SageMath does this, I believe using its "sphinxify" code: https://github.com/sagemath/sage/blob/develop/src/sage/misc/sphinxify.py. That is not easy to use out of the box — it has various SageMath specific things in it — but maybe you can adapt it.